# Built-in method for complex grouping of elements in a scala collection

Tags: scala, collections

I'm working on a problem where I need to group the items in a Scala collection by using a non-transitive predicate function. As an example, I might have a `Set(52**, 521*, 5211, 5212)` and also have:

```
predicate(52**, 521*) = true
predicate(52**, 5211) = true
predicate(52**, 5212) = true    
predicate(521*, 5211) = true
predicate(521*, 5212) = true
predicate(5211, 5212) = false
```

The stars are basically wildcards and can be equal to anything.

The result of grouping should look like:

```
Set(Set(52**,521*,5211), Set(52**,521*,5212))
```

Notice how the predicate holds true for all the items grouped together. I'm hoping to learn if there is a built-in method that can help achieve such behavior.

The predicate function is commutative.

Comment: The predicate will be commutative so the order doesn't matter. Updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that predicate is only the wildcard matching relation or it can be arbitrary function? Also can you please clarify rules for grouping. First of all, it's not technically "grouping", as element can appear in more than one "group". This operations looks more like combination. Is it true that you return only combinations that can't be extended by adding any other element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your "predicate" can be arbitrary function, there is bruteforce solution using Scala built-in methods. It just generates all combinations of elements and checks every pair of elements within the combination against `predicate`.

```
def predicate(s1:String, s2:String) =
  Map(
    Set("52**", "521*") -> true,
    Set("52**", "5211") -> true,
    Set("52**", "5212") -> true,
    Set("521*", "5211") -> true,
    Set("521*", "5212") -> true,
    Set("5211", "5212") -> false
  )(Set(s1,s2))

val input = List("52**", "521*", "5211", "5212")

val res = (2 to input.size).flatMap(input.combinations)
  .filter(_.combinations(2).forall {
  case Seq(x1, x2) => predicate(x1, x2)
}).map(_.toSet)

val maximalRes = res.filter(r => 
  !res.exists(x => x != r && r.diff(x).isEmpty))
```

Result:

```
res = Vector(Set(52**, 521*), Set(52**, 5211), Set(52**, 5212), Set(521*, 5211), Set(521*, 5212), Set(52**, 521*, 5211), Set(52**, 521*, 5212))
maximalRes = Vector(Set(52**, 521*, 5211), Set(52**, 521*, 5212))
```

As I said, this approach is bruteforce, hence very inefficient. Knowing more about your `predicate` function, possible elements and input size will help to come up with more efficient solution.